# cannot access object in class scope

Tags: c++, .net

I can access member StartTest when it's inside 'h' file but not
when it's inside 'cpp' file. In the cpp I get the Lnk errors.

```
// Form1.h
// class outside of generated namespace problem
// this was created using VS 2012 C++ wizard
namespace w32t {
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form {
  O O O // generated stuff left out
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include "aTest.h"

 private: System::Void Test_OnClick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
 {
      aTest* objTest = new aTest();         // create aTest pointer
  this->InternalRoutine(objTest);
  }
  void InternalRoutine(aTest* objExt)
  {
      aTest* objX = objExt;         // copy aTest pointer
      objX->StartTest(123);         // call to aTest::StartTest
  }                                 // works inside aTest.h
 }; // end class Form1              // NOT inside aTest.cpp
}  // end namespace w32t

//test.h
class aTest{
public:
int iTest;

aTest()
{ 
    iTest = 0;
};
~aTest(){};
/*  void StartTest(int iArg0)       // when this is part
    {                               // of the build, the
        iTest = iArg0;              // call from Internal using
    }                               // objX->StartText(123);
*/                                  // works.
};

// test.cpp                         // when "StartTest" is commented
#include "stdafx.h"                 // out in the class and this is
#include "testHeader.h"             // included the app will not build  
void aTest::StartTest(int iArg0)    // !!this will not link!!
{                                   // error LNK2028: unresolved token
    iTest = iArg0;                  // error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
}
```

The 'cpp' file causes the link error when the member StartTest is defined within. When the member is commented out and implemented inside the 'h' file it works okay. This is very simple code it should work.

Comment: This is a VS 2012 form.h with one button; initializing a class in an 'h' file; then calling a member in a 'cpp' file. The member in the cpp file generates the dread LNK2028-LNK2019.

Comment: When the cpp member is placed in the h file the code compiles and links correctly. In the above listing I forgot to show the member prototype but it's there in my test.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the function `StartTest()` in `test.h`. To do so, add the line

```
StartTest(int iArg0);
```

underneath the line

```
public:
```

Also include `test.h` in `test.cpp`

Comment: I forgot to put the prototype back for this listing. Adding the prototype does not help.

Answer (score 0):

The class aTest stuff in test.h does one main thing - it lists all of the member variables and member functions inside this class. It can also hold the code that implements the member functions but this is not necessary, you could have the line:

```
void StartTest(int iArg0);
```

inside test.h and this would state that there is such a member function, but that it is to be found elsewhere. If you do put this in test.h I think that the implementation of StartTest() in test.cpp will be OK.

And include test.h in test.cpp as Jay points out.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion in the description. I had a prototype and it still would not work correctly when the member is in the cpp file.

Comment: OK, I understand, so you have a clean pair of files one .h and the other .cpp. Then the only thing I can think of is that your link stage of the build is not including test.obj (or test.o depending). As a first experiment I would introduce a deliberate error in test.cpp just to prove to yourself that it is even being compiled.

Comment: I did and it is being compiled, there is a testSource.obj file.

Comment: OK, so how sure are you that testSource.obj is being included in the link? For example, is there anything else in test.cpp (or is that testSource.cpp) that is not giving linker errors?

Comment: According to the w32t.log I'm sure that testSource.obj is being included if there are no bugs in VS2012 Solution Explorer creating a good make. I've tried clean and rebuild several times.

Comment: OK, I'm pretty-much beaten. There is something about the function in the cpp file that is causing it to be inaccessible, but I cannot think what. Aha! A flash of inspiration - not sure I know what I'm talking about though - in your main code you are including aTest.h inside the namespace w32t section - try moving it and stdafx.h to earlier, outside the scope of the namespace declaration. I think that aTest is being created inside the w32t namespace but a function in test.cpp will be outside that namespace ... while the prototype in aTest.h is inside it ... so not found.

Comment: I'm surprised that worked. Thanks. Inside the w32t scope it could not resolve a defined external, yet outside the w32t scope it could. That's bizarre. Thanks again. To clarify: I moved the two include files above the namespace w32t. Class aTest is now outside of w32t while the object is created inside w32t and has access to all of the class's definitions.